# Axios.post request successfull, but callback in .then(res => ... doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, passport.js

I am developing a full stack application with a NodeJS backend and a ReactJS frontend. I am using PassportJS to do authentication with login and password.
Here is my post request in the back end when a user logs in:

```
    let username;
    let uid;
    
    app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
      passport.authenticate('local',
      (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
    
        if (!user) {
          return res.send({"message": "Password or username is incorrect"});
        }
    
        req.logIn(user, function(err) {
          if (err) {
            return next(err);
          }
          username = user.username;
          uid = user._id;
    
          return res.send({"message": "User Authenticated"});
      
        });
    
      })(req, res, next);
    });
```

Here is my front end ReactJS code:

```
function LoginPage(props) {
    const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    const SERVER_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL;
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const handleLogin = async() => {
      // props.onChange();
        axios.post(SERVER_URL + "/login", {"username": username, "password": password})
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res.data);
          console.log("login successful");
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err.data))
      }
    return (
        <span>
      Login<br/>
        <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>
          <label>Username: 
            <input type="text" value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} />
          </label><br></br>
          <label>Password: 
            <input type="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
          </label><br/>
          <input type="submit" value="Login" />
          </form><br/>
    </span>
    );
  }
  
  export default LoginPage;
```

The post request works in that once it is logged in, passportJS middleware creates req.user object. I have another request in the backend that fetches this data. However, it is only triggered when I manually refresh the page, triggering the render of the user's profile page instead of login (I use a boolean isAuthenticated to do this)

Even though the post is successful, once I click the submit button, none of the "res.send" functions send anything to the client side. i.e. "login successful" nor "res.data" show up. I tried using useNavigate() to redirect but it wasn't executing either. The function in .then() does not execute. none of the "res.send" functions do anything. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `return res.send({"message": "User Authenticated"});`

Comment: You should not be registering your `app.get("/user")` route inside the `app.post('/login')` handler

Comment: @Phil this is entirely correct, and renders my answer moot. I was parsing this incorrectly.

Comment: @silencedogood easy to miss when you just wouldn't expect to see that there

Comment: @Phil I removed it, and tried yochanan suggestion, still did not work, console log didnt show anything unfortunately :/

Comment: The code in your question needs to be updated to match

Comment: @Phil just updated it!